# Spring OAuth 2 Unique User for a Client

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm securing my REST API using Spring OAuth 2. In there, I have number of clients and under each client there's users. Eg; Client A has users A1 and A2 and client B has users B1 and B2. But I can't find a way to define the relation between clients and users. ( A1 belongs to A not to B etc .. ). I'm using in memory user details service as bellow,

```
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
    .withUser("bob").password("abc123").roles("USER");
}
```

and a custom client details service. Is there a way to define which users are belongs to which client ?

Comment: afaik Spring Security knows nothing about OAuth 1/2 stuff. OAuth security module extends/overrides classes in Spring Security module - that's how it works. So, as a result of that, Spring Security doesn't know about clients/users as it defines OAuth standard. That's why you cannot define such a relation using Spring Security config. Investige into Spring Security OAuth config.

Comment: I went through OAuth config articles. But it seems like there's no default implementation for this. As far as I understood, I have to write a custom configuration to AuthorizationServerEndpointConfigurer. Is that what I have to do ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You don't need it for OAuth2.